# What are Fakes assembly in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

There are a lot of question on how to add Fakes Assembly but no one on what they are and what they are used for.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fakes are used to mock or stub code for testing purposes. E.g., instead of connecting directly to a database in a unit test you create a fake of the class that accesses the database that "fakes" just enough behavior to be used instead of the real database. This isolates the unit test from the remaining system.

You can read more about fakes in [Isolating Code Under Test with Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx).

Comment: Also worth nothing is that you need Visual Studio Premium or Ultmate to get the Fakes-stuff, many seem to believe that they will get this with VS Professional.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft Fakes framework, helps you to test your code, when you want to use some external variables whose values change randomly (like stocks) and you are using that in your code (you want to test this code, without bothering about the external factors). Another case could be testing something which i not yet complete.

So in your code you have something which you want to test + Some external factors.

> Fakes would help you by replacing external factors by your code.